# Receiving binary data through http

Tags: c++, http

I am currently working on a server which will receive images uploaded from the client. The client can send the image through a http form as shown below.

```
 <form method="post" action="http://localhost:7074" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="myfile">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

On my server side, I followed the beej tutorial on creating a socket and listening for connection. Upon uploading the image from the client side, this is what my server read from the buffer:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7074
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.15
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------13305569846927610321194789130
Content-Length: 3273

-----------------------------13305569846927610321194789130
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="0-adidas-logo.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

����
```

From the received data, I presumed that the beginning portion is the http headers and the actual binary data for my image is after the line  "Content-Type: image/jpeg". So I printed the rest of the buf to a file and save it as a jpeg file, but when I open it up, I get the error "Improper call to jpeg library in state 201. So I was wondering if there is anything wrong with the steps that I had mentioned earlier, as I am struck at this stage for quite some time.

Comment: Please add code for someone to be able to help you.
Do you save to the file according to the `Content-Length` field received in the http headers (usually the file isn't sent all at once, it is broken down into several packets)?

Comment: One thing to note is that the HTTP header ends with \r\n. Make sure you aren't writing the \n or the \r\n to the jpeg.

Comment: I strongly recommend you use a library to do this rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing your http response,

The 'form-data' boundary header is terminated with a \r\n
the data thereafter is your binary data.

the binary data ends at the next occurance of the 'boundary' terminated with '--'

eg:

```
-----------------------------13305569846927610321194789130--
```

the data size is everything from the \r\n to the last byte before the boundary.

Other factoids are that the Post's http header has a content-size. that is for ALL content including the multipart sections.

Read more about processing form data here (See section 3.3 use of multipart/form-data):

```
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt
```

and for content disposition

```
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt
```